# How to redirect one page to another page using React native JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Page redirection using React JS,
Initially have the App.js it show the home screen need to redirect the new page in react iOS solution.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org). It does a lot of standard navigation that uses the same animations as native iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using  [this](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) npm package. You could redirect your users programatically, after a certain timeout or on a button press.